# database connection issue after moving from tomcat-dbcp to tomcat-jdbc connection pooling

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, connection-pooling, apache-commons-dbcp, jdbc-pool

In my spring+hibernate based web application, I recently moved from tomcat-dbcp to tomcat-jdbc connection pooling.
After that I am facing a connection issue.
here are the settings I have:

JNDI.xml:

```
<entry key="datasource">
                <bean class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" destroy-method="close" singleton="false">
                    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"></property>
                    <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=TESTDB"></property>
                    <property name="username" value="testuser"></property>
                    <property name="password" value="testpwd"></property>
                </bean>
            </entry>
```

Earlier above datasource was tomcat-dbcp.

applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

Code to get the datasource properties:

```
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource basicDataSource = (org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource) context.lookup("datasource");
String password = basicDataSource.getPassword();
log.debug("jndi data source pwd::"+password);
```

When I try to look at the password in debug mode in eclipse - it is shown as

```
Password not available as DataSource/JMX operation.
```

On application startup it tries to login into the database with this info and get some details. At that point I see the following error in the logs:

```
12142 [main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory - Initializing connection provider: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider
13269 [main] WARN org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 18456, SQLState: S0001
13269 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Login failed for user 'testuser'.
13269 [main] WARN org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Could not obtain connection to query metadata
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'testuser'.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:197)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:246)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:83)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:2529)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:1905)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:41)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:1893)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:4874)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1400)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1045)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:817)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:700)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:842)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:267)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:176)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:655)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:597)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:460)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:130)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:112)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:99)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:123)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:81)
at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:111)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2119)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2115)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1339)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:855)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:774)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1460)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1398)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:540)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:842)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:416)
at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:161)
at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:51)
```

The SQL Server logs say:

```
2014-05-16 16:53:16.44 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 8.
2014-05-16 16:53:16.44 Logon       Login failed for user 'testuser'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: 10.1.10.21]
```

All was working well when I had tomcat-dbcp. The user id and password are valid and I can connect to the DB with these credentials. This issue seems to be a tomcat-jdbc triggered one.

Am I missing any configuration?
I am not sure what is failing here and am unable to proceed with debug. Any pointers will be helpful!

Comment: Something is wrong with what you have reported. In the stack trace, it says the username is `ACCE1135support` and in your configuration and the error log it says `testuser`. Which is it?

Comment: Apologies, put in the correct stack now. was trying with 2 different users.

Comment: Where is the DEBUG log with the password shown? You may want to dump-out the username as well, just in case.